# Using a variable for #define

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Libcurl uses the following to define the email recipient:

```
#define RECIPIENT "<bla@bla.com>"
```

But what if I don't want to hard code the recipient? I want a user to be able to supply his/her own email address, so I need to find a way to do this:

```
std::string emailreceiver = "bla@bla.com";
#define RECIPIENT = emailreceiver
```

The recipient is used in this line:

```
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, RECIPIENT);
```

I'm assuming I can't simply change this to

```
std::string emailreceiver = "bla@bla.com";
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, emailreceiver);
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because it seemed to good to be true. And it was, but not by much ;) + I'm still curious on if it's possible to assign a variable to a #define or not.

Comment: You don't want `=` or `;` in your macro definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Curl expects a C string (`const char *`), not a C++ string (`std::string`). So try:

```
std::string emailreceiver = "bla@bla.com";
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, emailreceiver.c_str());
```

There's no need to use a `#define` at all, that was just an example.

Comment: Will test this when I get home. Just out of curiosity, is it at all possible to assign a variable to a #define ? You know, in case I want to go lazy mode ;)

Comment: No it isn't - the #define is replaced during the per-processor stage

Comment: @natli: a `#define` is a macro that gets expanded during compilation. If you try to do something like `#define RECEIPT email_receiver`, then anywhere you use `RECEIPT`, it'll just get expanded to the text `email_receiver`. That might work, but only if `email_receiver`'s type happens to be one that will work there.

Comment: If your code is already sprinkled with RECIPIENT you can `#define RECIPIENT emailreceiver.c_str()` (no semicolon!).

Answer (score 4):

Your last snippet is probably pretty close. From the looks of things, curl is expecting a C-style string though, so you *may* have to change it to:

```
std::string emailreceiver = "bla@bla.com";
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, emailreceiver.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

libcurl doesn't really do that.  The `#define` in your question most closely resembles a line in `docs/examples/smtp-multi.c`:

```
#define RECIPIENT "<recipient@example.com>"
```

The macro is used exactly once, later in the same source file:

```
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, RECIPIENT);
```

(Quoted lines are from curl version 7.23.0.)

As the file name implies, that's only an example.  In a real application, it's unlikely that you'd want to use a hardwired macro for a recipient name.

The declaration of `curl_slist_append`, in `curl.h`, is:

```
CURL_EXTERN struct curl_slist *curl_slist_append(struct curl_slist *,
                                                 const char *);
```

(Don't worry about the `CURL_EXTERN` or the `const` for now.)

So when you call `curl_slist_append`, the second argument has to be a `char*`.  In particular, it can be a string literal, either written directly in the call or resulting from a macro expansion.  But it can be *any* expression of type `char*`, as long as it points to a valid string.

You need decide how you want to determine the recipient e-mail address, and pass a pointer to that string (a C-style string, not a C++ `std::string`) as the second argument to `curl_slist_append`.  It probably doesn't make sense to use a macro for that purpose.  It was just a simple way for the example program to demonstrate what's going on.

As for your question in a comment: "I'm still curious on if it's possible to assign a variable to a #define or not." -- well, yes and no.  You don't *assign* anything to a `#define`.  A `#define` (macro definition) is a compile-time construct that causes any occurrence of the macro name to be replaced by the literal text of the macro definition.  For example, this:

```
#define RECIPIENT "<recipient@example.com>"
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, RECIPIENT);
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, "<recipient@example.com>");
```

(except that the latter doesn't leave `RECIPIENT` defined).  If you change the macro definition from `"<recipient@example.com>"` to **anything else you like**, then each occurrence of `RECIPIENT` will be replaced by whatever you wrote after `#define RECIPIENT`.

So you *could* do something like this:

```
char *recipient = get_recipient();
#define RECIPIENT recipient
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, RECIPIENT);
```

but there's no real point; you might as well just write:

```
rcpt_list = curl_slist_append(rcpt_list, recipient);
```

The preprocessor (the piece of the compiler that handles `#define` directives and macro expansions, among other things) has absolutely no clue about function calls, variables, and similar constructs.  It just does textual replacement without regard to what the text means.  (It's actually defined in terms of *tokens*.)

This means that you can abuse the preprocessor to do some dangerous things.  [Here's an example.](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/42)

Comment: Thanks for this, very informative. Am I to understand that as long as I put the macros in a <> at all times, they will never be evaluated as numbers? English isn't my primary language so I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're getting at with your example.

Comment: @natli: The example, 42.c, is almost deliberately confusing; you might be better off ignoring it for how.  It makes a point about macros that expand to arithmetic expressions, which doesn't apply here.  I don't understand what you mean by your question about <>.  The string literal happens to start with `'<'` and end with `'>'`, but that's not particularly relevant to anything.  The `RECIPIENT` macro defined in the example program is there to give a meaningful name to the string, with the purpose of making the sample code a bit easier to read and understand.